# How can I update form using AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to update a form via AJAX, so that there is no redirection when I submit a form. Now I have followed a tutorial but can't seem to make this work. When I click on the submit button nothing happens.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="profile_form" id="form" method="GET" action="include/profile/form/settings.php">
    <div class="profileFlex">
      <div class="settings-grid">
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label for="first_name">First name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstname[0]; ?>"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Last name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo $lastname[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>City</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<?php echo $city[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>ZIP code</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $zip[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Country</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $country[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="settings-grid">
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Telephone</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Telephone 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="phone2" value="<?php echo $phone2[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Mobile phone</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder">
            <label>Mobile phone 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-holder">
            <input type="text" name="mobile2" value="<?php echo $mobile2[0]; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder checkbox-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" id="sendmails" class="profilebox" name="checkbox" <?php if ($checkbox[0] == 'on') { print 'checked="checked" '; } ?>>
            <label for="sendmails">Allow website to send promotional emails</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-table">
          <div class="input-holder checkbox-holder">
            <input type="checkbox" class="profilebox" name="checkbox2" id="hide_mail" <?php if ($checkbox2[0] == 'on') { print 'checked="checked" '; } ?>>
            <label for="hide_mail">Hide email from listings</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update" />
  </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$detectUser = $_SESSION['token'];

include "../../../layout/config.php";

if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['last_name']);
    $address= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['address']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['city']);
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['zip']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['country']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['phone']);
    $phone2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['phone2']);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['mobile']);
    $mobile2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['mobile2']);

if(isset($_GET['checkbox'])){
    $checkbox = $_GET['checkbox'];
}else{
    $checkbox = "";
}

if(isset($_GET['checkbox2'])){
    $checkbox2 = $_GET['checkbox2'];
}else{
    $checkbox2 = "";
}

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', address='$address', city='$city', zip='$zip', country='$country', phone='$phone', phone2='$phone2', mobile='$mobile', mobile2='$mobile2', checkbox='$checkbox', checkbox2='$checkbox2' WHERE `token` = '$detectUser'"; 

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}

?>
```

**jQuery AJAX:**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#update').click(function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            url: "include/profile/form/settings.php", //php page URL where we post this data to save in database
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (strMessage) {
                $('#message').text("strMessage");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I know this question has been asked many times, but Im just now first time facing AJAX, so any help will mean a lot! Thanks!

Comment: You are sending POST data with ajax request (data in body), but expecting GET data in your PHP script (data in url).

Comment: Replace your `$('#message').text("strMessage");` with `$('#message').html(strMessage);`

Comment: Tried both and it didnt fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `async` to `false`. I also suggest adding an `error()` callback

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#update').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            url: "include/profile/form/settings.php", //php page URL where we post this data to save in database
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (strMessage) {
                $('#message').text(strMessage);
            },
            error: function(ts) {
                console.log(ts)
            },
            async: false
        });
    });
});
```

You should also make sure that you are checking for `$_POST` in your php script rather than `$_GET`.

Comment: When the async is false in console i get this: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: I also replaced all GET with the POST in my php file but still when I click on the button nothing happens.

Comment: You should try and $_POST from a dummy page to include/profile/form/settings.php and see what happens. You usually dont get error messages back through AJAX calls from the script, just nothing happens. Clearly the call is sent (so you have the right url), it also doesnt have any errors (because error function isnt echoed), so I think something is wrong in your script that you are POSTing to.